# Oracle Syntax Error on Prompt command when using Flyway

Tags: oracle, flyway

While the scrip is successful using sqlplus, but using flyway maven plugin, fails with below error:

```
...
[ERROR] Message    : ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
...
[ERROR] Line       : 3
[ERROR] Statement  : PROMPT Creating Sequence
```

not sure if it is a bug in flyway plugin or migration script?

Comment: Check for empty lines inside SQL statements. They are not allowed as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sqlplus-specific command unknown to the Oracle database & JDBC driver, hence the error-message. Check out dbms_output as an alternative: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/DBMS_OUTPUT